# Checkbox is not checked in React Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I developed a component for checkbox using React Formik Library.Below is my code

```
const CheckBoxGroup = (props) => {
 const { label,name,options,...rest } = props
  return ( 
  <React.Fragment>
<label htmlFor={name}> {label} </label>
<div className='form-check form-check-inline'>
    <Field  name={name} id={name} {...rest} >
        {
            ({field}) => {
               return options.map( (option) => {
                   
                    return ( <React.Fragment key={option.key}> 
                     
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                        id={option.value}  {...field} value={option.value}
                        checked={field.value.includes(option.value)}
                       />
                        <label class="form-check-label" htmlFor={option.value}>{option.key}</label>
                    </React.Fragment>)
                })
            }
           
        }
    </Field>
    <ErrorMessage name={name} component={TextError} />
</div>
</React.Fragment>
 );
}
```

Interesting part is that when checked property is present the checkbox is not cheked but if i remove checked property it is checked.what is the reason?

Answer (score 4):

In my case use value atribute as number but works only with string

```
<Field
                              className="form-check-input"
                              type="checkbox"
                              name="idsProfiles"
                              id={item.defaultText}
                              value={item.id.toString()}
                              aria-label={item.defaultText}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={item.defaultText}>
                              {item.defaultText}
                            </label>
```

Comment: <Field
                                  className="form-check-input"
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  name="idsProfiles"
                                  id={item.defaultText}
                                  value={item.id.toString()}
                                  aria-label={item.defaultText}
                                />
                                <label htmlFor={item.defaultText}>
                                  {item.defaultText}
                                </label>

Answer (score 0):

you can check the docs on the formik web page, here is a local implementation to try the demo checkbox and it's running ok, i used the last formik lib version.

here is the example from formik site: [formik checkboxex codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/formik/formik/tree/master/examples/checkboxes?from-embed)

***i cannot replicate you code because you miss the inputs on the props

here is what i run on local:

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Field, Formik ,Form } from 'formik';
import './App.css';

function App() {


  ///FORMIK DOCS:
  ///https://formik.org/docs/examples/checkboxes

const CheckBoxGroup = (props) => {
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

     return ( 
      <Formik
      initialValues={{
        toggle: false,
        checked: [],
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        await sleep(500);
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>        
          <label>
            <Field type="checkbox" name="toggle" />
            {`${values.toggle}`}
          </label>       
          <div id="checkbox-group">Checked</div>
          <div role="group" aria-labelledby="checkbox-group">
            <label>
              <Field type="checkbox" name="checked" value="One" />
              One
            </label>
            <label>
              <Field type="checkbox" name="checked" value="Two" />
              Two
            </label>
            <label>
              <Field type="checkbox" name="checked" value="Three" />
              Three
            </label>
          </div>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
    );
   }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {CheckBoxGroup()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```